# Problems with outlook 365 when using it as a client for dovecot/postfic server

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm having trouble getting outlook 365 to work with my debian based email server. I'm running latest versions of postfix and dovecot on the server, using letsencrypt certificates for server authentication and username/password for client authentication.

For the last cca. 2 weeks the one person who uses the server with an outlook365 client is having problems. It started with neither imap nor smtp working, but imap seems to have gotten fixed after a reinstalation. Unfortunately the smtp still doesn't work. It behaves very strangely too. Outlook seems to pretend that it has sent the emails but they never arrive and sometimes instead an undeliverable response comes back.

I can send and recieve emails on the server from both thunderbird and outlook 2019. Anyone have any ideas what might be the problem?

Edit: This is what the non delivery message looks like:

```
We couldn't deliver your message.

Original message details
Created date: 10/20/2022 4:28:52 PM
Sender address: OutlookSender@domain.cz
Recipient addresses: Recipient@otherdomain.cz
Subject: Test1


Technical details

MessageDeliveryFailedException: Could not deliver the message [len=70, data=00000000779B644314817748B2089D3C3EA2FE850700BAC6962D0EEB3344AD2F3E1486C6DB6000000000010F0000BAC6962D0EEB3344AD2F3E1486C6DB600000007AC9C80000] sent at 10/20/2022 4:29:23 PM.
Failure code: 332
```

In the meantime I've found a post that seems related which lays the blame squarely at microsoft's feet. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-app-for-mac-failure-code-332/4b467e84-3361-45c4-bf32-e794fca4c7f2 .

It's just one unofficial source though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, does the issue only occur to the specific user?

Could the specific user receive mails in outlook on web?

Could you share the NDR information for further troubleshooting and remember to remove your privacy information?

Comment: It is just one user, but he's the only one using outlook 365. The user should be using the outlook 365 client application in parallels under mac. I have added the NDR to the question.

Comment: To narrow down this issue if it is related with user account or outlook for mac, we still want to know if the issue only occurs to the specific user send mails when using outlook 365 for mac? In outlook web and outlook for windows work well? If all work well except for outlook for mac, refer to the blog to troubleshoot the issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-can-t-send-or-receive-messages-with-outlook-for-mac-57c6d42c-3a4e-4f93-914a-212efe650a04 If the issue still persists in outlook on web and outlook for windows, you may need to contact administrator to repair user's account.

Comment: I'm the administrator and I don't have access to any outlook 365 other than this one persons. I do have access to normal outlook 2019 and it works fine from there.

Comment: Based on your description, the issue may be related with outlook for mac, you could contact outlook for mac support to get further troubleshooting.